# WiX - using property within a property

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX 3.10 installer that installs an add-on module for an existing application. For this reason I use RegistrySearch to obtain the installation folder where the add-on should be put. After that an already pre-existing (meaning this is part of the base application and not the add-on) utility in the same directory must be executed with some parameters.

I tried this:

```xml
    <Property Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <RegistrySearch Id='InstallPathRegistry' Type='raw' Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\Vendor\Application' Name='InstallPath' Win64='no'/>
    </Property>

    <Condition Message="Application installation folder not found.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR INSTALLFOLDER]]>
    </Condition>

    <Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value="RegAddOn.exe /f [INSTALLFOLDER]\Addon.RegFile" />
    <CustomAction Id="QtExec" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check" />




<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="QtExec" OnExit="success"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Unfortunately, `[INSTALLFOLDER]` is not resolved. Obviously, as I also get a compiler warning about this.

How can I resolve the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your warning says what to do:

```
Warning     The 'X1' Property contains '[X2]' in its value which is an illegal reference to another property.  If this value is a string literal, not a property reference, please ignore this warning.  To set a property with the value of another property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value attributes.
```

Note: **use a CustomAction with Property and Value attributes.**

So you need to define your property with no value

```
<Property Id="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value=" " />
```

and use custom action to fill it

```
<CustomAction Id="SetProp" Property="WixQuietExecCmdLine" Value="RegAddOn.exe /f [INSTALLFOLDER]\Addon.RegFile"></CustomAction>
```

and run it before your current custom action

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetProp" OnExit="success"/>
  <Custom Action="QtExec" After="SetProp"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Also check out the document on this under "Deferred" execution: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html